# Multiple folders in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Originally I have a windows form project in my local machine, the codes are under the root. The code repository is TFS 2010. Now I put the codes into different folders(N-Tier).

I want to check and back in the codes to TFS. Should I delete the originally structure and remap it?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to do a Move operation from within Source Control Explorer to Move/Rename folders.  This way you ensure that TFS handles the move properly and preserves history.

Otherwise you can just do a delete of the old folders, and Adds on the new folders/files.  However, I would try to avoid this as you'll lose history.